# Connecting a USB 3.0 connector to USB 3.1 Gen 2 front panel connector

Tags: usb, motherboard, sata

My Asus ROG Strix x470F has a USB 3.1 Gen 2 front panel connector. My multicard reader has only a USB 3.0 (internal) connector.

I found this product: “CY USB 3.1 Front Panel Header to USB 3.0 20Pin Header Extension Cable for ASUS Motherboard 20cm”

[image]

This would be exactly what i need, but the reviews don’t look promising for my needs.

I couldn't find any alternatives. I have been looking for USB 3.1 Gen 1 to SATA but no luck there.

What would you do to connect the multi-card reader to the motherboard?

**Edit to answer questions:**

The [Manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/ROG_STRIX-X470-F-GAMING/E14093_ROG_STRIX_X470-F_GAMING_UM_V2_WEB.pdf) states on page 1-12. that there is one USB 3.1 Gen 2 connector and one USB 3.1 Gen 1 Connector. What i forgot to mention is, that my case already uses the mainboards USB 3.1 Gen 1 Connector. My card reader has an usb 3.1 Gen 1 connector as well. Therefore i have 2 USB 3.1 Gen 1 Cables which somehow have to fit into 1 USB 3.1 Gen 1 socket and 1 USB 3.1 Gen 2 Socket. I thought of sata because i have some sata connectors left on my mainbard.

Comment: `USB 3.0` is also known as `USB 3.1 Gen 1`.  Why would converting USB  to SATA be helpful?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm confused, when I look at this motherbaords user guide, it shows the 20-pin header you need on the board for your multicard reader to connect to an no internal "3.1" ports that would be appropriate for that cable.

Comment: i modified my first post to answer your questions

Comment: That is the type of cable you need then... we do not give shipping advice.

Comment: "My multicard reader has only a USB 3.0 (internal) connector." -  What is "your multicard reader"? What kind of "internal" connector does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new internal system connector [introduced about a year ago](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB3p1_Front_Panel_CabCon_Implment_Doc_Rev1p1.pdf), and the connectors started to [appear on the market](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Neue-Mainboard-Buchse-fuer-USB-3-1-Anschluesse-an-der-PC-Front-3634193.html) since [early 2017](https://smallformfactor.net/news/usb-3-1-motherboard-connector-revealed).

[image]

Here is the suggested use:
[image]

If your "multicard reader" does have the older 20-pin (2mm pitch blue) internal connector that mates to the cable shown in your question, this is the only way (and the right way) to use the new "U31G2_C1" on-board connector, regardless of "non-promising reviews".

It has to be noted that the USB 3.1 (both Gen1 and especially Gen2), is fairly sensitive to quality of cables and especially to how wires are assembled inside overmolds, so it is possible that early (non-certified) implementations of cables might have signal integrity issues and don't work to user's expectations. So you either search for USB-IF certified cable-adapter, or try to push some luck buying different cables from different manufacturers.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed info. I'll search for USB-IF certified cable-adapter. If i do not find any i'll have to wait. The other ports are still working.